# Suppress avc: denied

Tags: android

I am looping through the files inside /proc but when I check to see if it's a file or directory I get a permission warning.  Can I suppress this warning?

```
File[] files = new File("/proc").listFiles();
for (File file : files) {
  if (file.isFile()) {
    // really cool stuff
  }
}
```

each loop produces this ( for some files, not all of them).

```
com.example.package﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:611729): avc: denied { search } for name="1" dev="proc" ino=6096 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

I don't want it to print that message, how can I prevent that?

Comment: I doubt you can on an unrooted device, other than by not doing what you're doing with `/proc`. That's an SELinux policy message, and ordinary Android SDK apps AFAIK cannot mess with SELinux settings.

Comment: I also have the issue while running commands via Android's `Runtime.exec()`. The warnings flood the system log pretty much. What a mess.